# Ajax status errors while trying to refresh data

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I need to refresh my data at certain points in my application (after a pop up form is closed). The application in essence allows users to submit forms, save data, and reopen the forms and view/edit the data.

I'm calling an ajax request from a javascript function. The ajax then calls the java function, which in debugging appears to execute without issue, but right after that's performed, I got an ajax error with status 200. I read some things online, and instead of using a POST type, changed it to a GET, but now I get a 500 status, and can't access the data anymore; my belief is that I'm being logged out.

This is the javascript/ajax function:

```
function refreshData(){ 
  $.ajax({
      url: "./profileEntriesAction.do",
      data: "toMethod=refreshData",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(data){
          alert('success :: ' + data);
      }
  });
}
```

On the java side (profileEntriesAction), I have:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ActionForward refreshProfile(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws Exception{

    HttpSession objSession = request.getSession();
    User user = (User) objSession.getAttribute(Constants.USER_KEY);
    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
    ActionMessages messages = new ActionMessages();
    ProfileBean pBean = (ProfileBean)objSession.getAttribute("pBean");
    ProfileForm pForm = (ProfileForm)objSession.getAttribute("ProfileForm");


    if (user == null)
            return (mapping.findForward("logon"));  

    //get connection to db from the pool using a static method
    Connection objConn = StartUpServlet.getPoolConnection();

    try{        
    System.out.println("refreshProfile 2");

    /////////////////////////////  
    /////////////////////////////
    IntDAO iDAO = new IntDAO();
    // get lists data
    if (!pForm.isNoInts()) {
            Object[] arr = iDAO.getLists(objConn, pBean.getProfileId());
            pForm.setList((ArrayList<Ints>) arr[0]);
    }

    /////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////
    }catch(SQLException ex){ 
     if(ex.getErrorCode() == Constants.SQL_ERROR_CODE_UNACCESSIBLE_RESOURCE && ex.getSQLState().equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.SQL_SQL_STATE_UNACCESSIBLE_RESOURCE)){
     objLogger.error("DB maintenance :\n" + ex.getMessage());
     errors.add(Globals.ERROR_KEY, new ActionMessage("error.db.maintenance"));
    } else {
      objLogger.error("Error while refreshing the profile - Profile Id "+ pBean.getProfileId()+" :\n" + ex.getMessage());
      errors.add(Globals.ERROR_KEY, new ActionMessage("error.entry.refresh.profile", "Profile"));
            }
      if(objConn != null)
         objConn.rollback();
    }catch(Exception e){
      objLogger.error("Error while refreshing the profile - Profile Id "+ pBean.getProfileId()+" :\n" + e.getMessage());
       errors.add(Globals.ERROR_KEY, new ActionMessage("error.entry.refresh.profile", "Profile"));
       if(objConn != null)
          objConn.rollback();
    }finally {
       if(objConn!= null && !objConn.getAutoCommit())
           objConn.setAutoCommit(true);
       // return the connection to the pool using a static method
       StartUpServlet.rtnPoolConnection(objConn);                      
    }       

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        saveErrors(objSession, errors);
    }
    if(!messages.isEmpty()){
        saveMessages(objSession, messages);
    }

    return  mapping.findForward("success"); 
    //return null;
}
```

I've tried commenting out the entire contents of the java function and just returning the mapping.findForward("success"); but I still get the same errors.

Comment: What exception do you get in Java console when you do POST request?

Comment: @ArinCool I get  a java.lang.NullPointerException.